# Backlog view - Reorder tasks

Tags: azure-devops, tags

I was able to reorder my tasks, meaning to move them up or down. But it is not working for all of them at the moment. After reordering my task in the Backlog view, after leaving the page and coming back, it’s come back as it was originally. And my reorder was not taken into account.

Have you ever faced this issue ?

Thank you.

I tried to look into the settings, to reorder the tasks several times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.